# False positives in faster-rcnn object detection

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I'm training an object detector using tensorflow and the `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco` model and am experiencing a lot of false positives when classifying on a video.

After some research I've figured out that I need to add negative images to the training process.

How do I add these to `tfrecord` files? I used the csv to `tfrecord` file code provided in the tutorial [here](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py).

Also it seems that ssd has a `hard_example_miner` in the config that allows to configure this behaviour but this doesn't seem to be the case for faster rcnn? Is there a way to achieve something similar on faster rcnn?

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue with faster RCNN, although you **cannot** actually **use hard_example_miner** with the **faster RCNN** model, you can add some **background images**, ie. images with no objects (Everything remains the same, except there is not object tag in the xml for that particular picture)

One more thing that actually worked wonders for me was using the **[imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) library**, you can *augment the images and the bounding boxes using the same script*. Try and increase the training data by 10 or 15 times, and then I would suggest you to train again to around 150000-200000 steps.

These two steps helped me reduce the number of false positives effectively.

Comment: "except there is not object tag in the xml for that particular picture"..you mean there should an XML file for background included in training without object tag?